# How do I redirect a dir to another on linux?

Tags: java, linux, jvm, redhat, java-7

For Example: How can I redirect the dir `/tmp` to `/home/userOne/tmp` ?

About Why I Do That: Cause I am a common user on the worker linux server, no previleges to read, write and execute the `/temp` dir. No root, I can't ask for the power cause these's too many difficult. So, I can't use the jps, jstat, jconsole... commands, they are all throwing `NullPointerException`.

There is the infomations about that:

```sh
[userOne@VM-GWZD01-177117 ~]$ stat /tmp
  File: `/tmp'
  Size: 4096        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: fd04h/64772d    Inode: 2           Links: 8
Access: (0750/drwxr-x---)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2019-11-01 11:36:07.000000000 +0800
Modify: 2019-12-31 03:50:02.000000000 +0800
Change: 2019-12-31 03:50:02.405056408 +0800
```

```sh
[userOne@VM-GWZD01-177117 ~]$ ls /tmp
ls: cannot open directory /tmp: Permission denied
```

```sh
[userOne@VM-GWZD01-177117 ~]$ jps
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.jvmstat.perfdata.monitor.protocol.local.LocalVmManager.activeVms(LocalVmManager.java:148)
    at sun.jvmstat.perfdata.monitor.protocol.local.MonitoredHostProvider.activeVms(MonitoredHostProvider.java:150)
    at sun.tools.jps.Jps.main(Jps.java:62)
```

Or can I set a dir to `java.io.tmpdir` as a global jvm-variable ?

This is the output of java.io.tmpdir:

```sh
[shxz_ftp@VM-GWZD01-177117 ~]$ java OutputJavaTmpDir
/tmp
```

Comment: `java -Djava.io.tmpdir=$HOME/tmp`

Comment: Something is very, _very_ strange with your `/tmp`. I've never seen it not `1777`. All sorts of _other_ things will also not work without a `TMPDIR`.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/362100/is-tmp-guaranteed-to-exist

Comment: @ElliottFrisch that's no useful, cause you have to add a main method at end of. It will not work well.

Comment: Did you check the `TMPDIR` environment variable? --- Anyway, rather than try to a workaround for Java, you should get the `/tmp` issue itself fixed. A non-working `tmp` folder makes no sense and will affect other programs too. Ask on https://unix.stackexchange.com/ or https://superuser.com/ if you need help with that.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike-  yeah, I know all about that the normal previleges to `/tmp`. I guess that's cause for the security policy, server manager changed it.

Comment: The `1` _is_ the security policy for `/tmp`: [sticky bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit)

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- however I think maybe I should apply for previleges from system-manager. that's a very lengthy process.

Comment: I question your sysadmin's competence...

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike-    hahahaha    I‘m....helpless.

Comment: Does `java -Djava.io.tmpdir=$HOME/tmp OutputJavaTmpDir` work? **And**, does `export TMPDIR=$HOME/tmp && java OutputJavaTmpDir` work? **And**, can you write a script to start your program? **And**, why have you not asked your sysadmin for support?